# c++: compilation error using map in c++ STL?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have the following code:

```
std::map<char,int> first;

first['a']=10;
first['b']=30;
first['c']=50;
first['d']=70;

int main ()
{
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

I'm having several compilations errors at:

```
first['a']=10;
first['b']=30;
first['c']=50;
first['d']=70;
```

saying:

> error: 'first' does not name a type

What can I do to get this to compile (and work, of course)?

Comment: This is a piece of code, not a question.

Comment: Can you specify what your specific error?  Also, you shouldn't be assigning to the map at global scope - is this in a function that you are not showing?

Comment: You don't populate a global `std::map<>` like that.

Comment: Problem with instructions at global scope, also edit your question to make it a question.

Answer (score 3):

You should move:

```
first['a']=10;
first['b']=30;
first['c']=50;
first['d']=70;
```

inside the `main` function body. Alternatively you can use any other function body. As [you can see](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a361b4d705db1460) that will lead to a successful compilation.

Alternatively you can initialize the `std::map` with an *initializer-list* (since C++11) such as:

```
std::map<char,int> first {
    {'a', 10},
    {'b', 30},
    {'c', 50},
    {'d', 70}
};
```

---

By the standard, the global namespace is defined as (at §3.3.6/3):

> The outermost declarative region of a translation unit is also a
>   namespace, called the global namespace.

At §7.3/1, a namespace is defined as:

> A namespace is an optionally-named declarative region.

Comment: An explanation as to why you can't do that at namespace scope would probably be useful to the OP.

Comment: Or, in C++11, give the map an initialiser, `map<...> first {{'a',10},...};`

Comment: @thokra, give me 5 minutes. :)

Comment: @Jefffrey: NP, I have to look in the standard as well. ;)

Comment: @thokra, this is actually harder than expected.

Comment: @Jefffrey: You kinda forgot the important part, following from the grammar in §7.3.1, stating that a namespace body can only contain an optional declaration sequence: `namespace-body: declaration-seq_opt`. It's astonishing how obvious it is in contrast to how long it takes to get to it. :) EDIT: However, now that I think about it, "A namespace is an optionally-named declarative region." actually says it all - but you have to think really hard. ;)

Comment: @thokra, eh. I've searched for at least half an hour after the last comment and still couldn't find anything as explicative as I would have wished.

Comment: @Jefffrey: Yeah ... would be awesome if the standard were written for humans. :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to put

```
first['a']=10;
first['b']=30;
first['c']=50;
first['d']=70;
```

into `main()` scope.

Answer (score 0):

Not a great question but here:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

// constructing maps
std::map<char,int> first;

int main ()
{
    // populate map
    first['a']=10;
    first['b']=30;
    first['c']=50;
    first['d']=70;

    std::map<char,int> second (first.begin(),first.end());

    std::map<char,int> third (second);

    std::map<char,int>::iterator i;
    char c;
    for(i=first.begin(),c='a';i!=first.end();i++,c++)
        std::cout<<first[c]<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```